# What is the task to Call build definition after release definition in different branches in VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have one requirement in VSTS,Currently as part of CI/CD process I have a build definition job and release definition job.The release definition will be called upon successful completion of build definition at the same time once the release definition will deploy the code to server I need to call test job which is configured in a separate build definition(which is in different branch).So I need the task name in VSTS how to call all the test build definition upon successful completion of  release definition.Please help me to find how to accomplish this task.can I do it through power shell script or task? If I can do through script,Please share me that script.

Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a build definition in a release definition, there are two ways: PowerShell task or extension task (such as Queue New Build).

#### Option 1:  use PowerShell task to queue build by REST API

**prerequisitions:**

1. Get the build definition id

   In the build definition which you want to be called, get the build definition ID: Edit build definition -> Variables Tab -> The value for system.definitionId is the ID need to use. As be example the build definition id is `32`:
   [image]
2. add a Personal Access Token (PAT)

   In your VSTS account -> click your profile -> Security -> Personal access tokens Tab -> Add -> copy the new created token for later use.

   [image]
   [image]

Now add a Powershell task as below script:

```
$body = '
{
  "definition": {
    "id": <build definition ID>
  }
}
'
$bodyJson=$body | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output $bodyJson
$bodyString=$bodyJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
Write-Output $bodyString
$user="name"
$token="<personal access token>"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$Uri = "https://<account>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/<project>/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $bodyString -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
write-host $buildresponse
```

**Note:** In the script, you need to replace `<build definition ID>` as the value you find, replace `<personal access token>` as the real PAT you added, replace `<project>` with the real project name, and replace `<account>` as the name of your real VSTS account.

#### Option 2: use relate extension task in marketplace

Such as you can use use [Queue New Build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=delegen.DelegenQueueNewBuild), [Trigger Build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin%3Frealm), [Queue Build(s) task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jb.queue-build) etc to specify the build definition name and the json to queue the build.

- For the **Trigger Build task**, you just need to specify the build name and use PAT to authentication (`d1` is the build definition name for me to queue, you can replace with your own build definition name).

[image]

- For the **Queue build(s) task**, you can specify the JSON as below (queue the build for master branch):

  ```
   { "sourceBranch": "master", "parameters": { "system.debug": true } }
  ```

[image]

Comment: My VSTS  URL is: https://telematicsapps.visualstudio.com/_projects.When I tried with the URl (https://telematicsapps.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Git2/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0) which you shared I am getting error like below with replacement of my account name as : telematicsapps

Comment: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF200016: The following project does not exist: Git2. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Team Foundation Server.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.ProjectDoesNotExistWithNameException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"ProjectDoesNotExistWithNameException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Comment: `Git2` is my team project name, you should replace with your own team project name. And I updated it in my answer, you can replace the `<project>` as your own team project name.

Comment: I just installed Queue new task plugin,Its asking for build def name and Build Parameters (JSON).I have given build def name and what about Json?Is it required? I just want to test whether my build def is triggering or not after the release def.So I have added one releasetest def job in that I added the queue new build task and provided only the build def name in that task.But uts not throwing any error and even not triggering the build def too..What change is required?

Comment: Yes, you can find the json example as the sample request shows https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build. BTW: didn't you queue the build by PowerShell task successfully?

Comment: I just gone through the link which you shared.Kindly tell me what Json script I need to include in my queuw new build task in VSTS.As  I told you I am new to this.So asking.Please help me what json file and what content I need to include? Come to the poewrshell,I need to add my access token that I don't have access.I need to check with my manager.So please help me for the queue plugin task.Why we need to mention build parameters(Json) and what is the use of that?Please give me clarify.

Comment: Under Json task in queue new build task,I am running this command:Still its not triggering the build def.  https://projectname.visualstudio.com/abc/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0 Content-Type: application/json {   "definition": {     "id": 10   },   "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",   "parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"true\",\"BuildConfiguration\":\"debug\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"x64\"}" }.

Comment: Any body can help here Please?

Comment: I have to deal with other things right now, and I will update the json laster, thx.

Comment: I list the settings for two tasks to queue a new build, you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its really awesome.Now I could able to trigger my build definition after release definition.Really much Appreciating your kind help in your busy time.I will accept your answer now.